# See how many times the users executed report - CRM online v9

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-365-v9

In online version 9, is there a way to see how many times users executed specific report? It is possible on-premise by querying the ReportServer database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft came up with **Activity Logging** which you can enable/use/search the audit data from O365 Admin center. This covers a broader capability from O365 umbrella services including CRM user activities, but definitely we can get more useful telemetry/audit data/insights compared to previous solutions.

I see what you want as well.

> Report Viewed  - Logging when a report is viewed. Critical customer content information might be displayed on the report.

[Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/admin/enable-use-comprehensive-auditing#user-and-support-related-events)